# How to mock npm module with sinon/mocha

Tags: node.js, mocking, mocha.js, sinon, sinon-chai

I'm trying to test a function that calls the module `cors`. I want to test that `cors` would be called. For that, I'd have to stub/mock it.

Here is the function 
cors.js

```
const cors = require("cors");

const setCors = () => cors({origin: 'http//localhost:3000'});
module.exports = { setCors }
```

My idea of testing such function would be something like

cors.test.js

```
  describe("setCors", () => {
    it("should call cors", () => {
      sinon.stub(cors)

      setCors();
      expect(cors).to.have.been.calledOnce;

    });
  });
```

Any idea how to stub npm module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`mock-require`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-require) or [`proxyquire`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire)

Example with `mock-require`

```js
const mock = require('mock-require')
const sinon = require('sinon')

describe("setCors", () => {
  it("should call cors", () => {
    const corsSpy = sinon.spy();
    mock('cors', corsSpy);

    // Here you might want to reRequire setCors since the dependancy cors is cached by require
    // setCors = mock.reRequire('./setCors');

    setCors();
    expect(corsSpy).to.have.been.calledOnce;
    // corsSpy.callCount should be 1 here

    // Remove the mock
    mock.stop('cors');
  });
});
```

If you want you can define the mock on top of describe and reset the spy using `corsSpy.reset()` between each tests rather than mocking and stopping the mock for each tests.

Comment: I've tried it. And I got that it was called 0 times.

Comment: @Ndx try `setCors = mock.reRequire('.path/to/setCors')`, as I wrote in the comment, modules are cached by `require` so if your `setCors` module was required before you try to mock `cors` then you'll need to reRequire it.

Comment: even i also getting the same 0 always.. not able to find what i have missed here :(